# Unable to git clone bitbucket over ssh

Tags: ssl, ssh, bitbucket, git-clone

I've created public and private keys, and added the public key to the Bitbucket repository.
[image]

These private/public key pair is available in the `.ssh` folder of the user account I hope to clone to.
[image]

Attempting to clone with SSH produces a connection refused:
[image]

This lead me to believe that either the Bitbucket project/server is not configured for ssh, or maybe this is a firewall/port issue for my companies network. However, port 7999 and port 22 are open.

[image]

This lead me to investigate other means of cloning with ssh, but over http as described here (just in case if port 22 or 7999 was blocked): [https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/%C2%A0)

To do this I modified my ssh config as follows:

[image]

Doing this allowed me to atleast establish a connection with bitbucket, but it acts as if the request was bad:

[image]

This lead me to believe that maybe i signed the cert incorrectly so I attempted a flavor of this: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503851/how-to-generate-a-certificate-file-which-to-be-used-with-ssh-config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503851/how-to-generate-a-certificate-file-which-to-be-used-with-ssh-config%C2%A0)

To add the certificatefile provided in the ssh config. It sounded like I would need to add that public key of the private key used to sign the user key (that generated the certificate). However, I won't have access to the private key for the cert available on the bitbucket server.

Separately, I was able to grab the public cert from altssh.bitbucket.di2e.net:443 and I did try using this, but still got a bad request... This probably doesn't make sense to use since this is in PEM format, but I figured it was worth a try..

```
openssl s_client connect altssh.bitbucket.di2e.net:443 < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' > public.crt
```

I'm wondering if I've incorrectly signed the user key with the cert key, but would like advise on best steps to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: you have an nginx responding on 443, you probably have to set up more to have ssh on that hostname and port, probably need another IP address - the docs you linked seem to be for bitbucket.com, not the self hosted bitbucket

Comment: the bitbucket serve is hosted by another entity, but it appears to be configured similarly to the docs I linked.

Can you provide additional detail of what needs to be setup given nginx responding on 443?

Comment: nginx shouldn't listen on the $altsshIP:443, but ssh should. Like, the server probably needs two IPs, nginx listen on IP A ports 80 and 443, ssh listening on IP A ports 22 and 7999 and on IP B port 443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come to find out the bitbucket proxy server I was trying to connect to was not configured to handle altssh.bitbucket.di2e.net which caused the connection over :443 to get dropped.

Root of the issue was a combination of corporate firewall blocking 7999 to external (wasn't blocked internally), as well as `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine I was attempting to clone to not being configured to `AllowAgentForwarding`